# Python: How to solve bracket not closed error

Tags: python

following a tutorial I'm getting error "(" is not closed while using the exact same code:

```
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
  {
      "language": "Solidity",
      "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content" = simple_storage_file}}
  }
)
```

don't know where it's going wrong getting these errors:

```
"{" was not closedPylance
Expected parameter namePylance
```

and

```
Expected parameter namePylance
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to replace "=" for ":" I hope this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @adammaly004 mentioned, you can't have an `=` in a python dict. Replacing `"content" = simple_storage_file` with `"content": simple_storage_file` should solve your issue.

Full example:

```py
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
  {
      "language": "Solidity",
      "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}}
  }
)
```

Comment: If defining key/values in an existing `dict` you can have an equals sign, as `d['key1'] = 'val1'` but not using the more efficient `{…}` constructor, as stated. Might be where OP got confused(?).

Answer (score 0):

Thing is you can't have an "=" in a dict, where you construct it from `{}` and not this `dict()`

Here's examples of both

1.

```py
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {
            "SimpleStorage.sol": {
                "content": simple_storage_file
            }
        }
    }
)
```

You cannot use a "=" sign in above constructor
2.

```py
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    dict(
        languages="Solidity",
        sources = dict(
            SimpleStorage.sol = dict(
                content = simple_storage_file)
        )
    )
)
```

In your case the second method will not work, because you have a `.` in `SimpleStorage` when you have a `.` in something Python thinks it is like a module or class
So that's why this method won't work for this case

But it's handy to know

Answer (score 0):

i also faced the same problem. my code before i fixed

```
from django.urls import include, re_path
from EmployeeApp import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^department/$',views.departmentApi),
    re_path(r'^department/([0-9]+)$',views.departmentApi)

     re_path(r'^employee/$',views.employeeApi),
    re_path(r'^employee/([0-9]+)$',views.employeeApi)
]
```

```
 i was getting this error, "[" is not closed 
File "F:\Programming\DjangoAngularTutorial\DjangoAPI\EmployeeApp\urls.py", line 6
    re_path(r'^department/([0-9]+)$',views.departmentApi)
```

i fixed by adding , on line 6

```
from django.urls import include, re_path
from EmployeeApp import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^department/$',views.departmentApi),
    re_path(r'^department/([0-9]+)$',views.departmentApi),

     re_path(r'^employee/$',views.employeeApi),
    re_path(r'^employee/([0-9]+)$',views.employeeApi)
]
```